# Identifying specific iOS devices that are new or not popular like iPad 2018

Tags: ios, xcode, performance

An important feature of my game is that it is able to query and determine what device is running it and thus look up from a large table some statistics on it like what processor, physical screen size in inches, Apple Pencil support, Ram, PPI etc about the device. This information is crucial to tweaking the apps internal graphical and simulation settings.

I know there are plenty of libraries on GitHub that start to do this usually the process is something like:

```
var systemInfo = utsname()
uname(&systemInfo)
let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: systemInfo.machine)
```

And then they use that string to determine the device and qualities about it. My problem is I cant currently find what this might return for the iPad 2018 that was launched at the education event. Not only is this device very new it is also not very popular still I would like to detect it.

Furthermore rumor has it that 3 new phones will be released at the next Apple event. If I want to support those right as they come out how can I determine the proper strings for those?

I cant even begin to afford these devices just to get this information.

How do I determine what the code sample above will return on unknown devices like the iPad 2018? How does that code sample even work?

Also would I need a privacy policy on my app should I send a POST request to my server whenever I discover a device with an ID I do not know?